# Spin of the sounding rocket

Tags: rockets, sounding-rocket, spin-stabilisation

I saw a video of a sounding rocket, where the rocket`s outer body was spinning very fast. Why does that happen?

Comment: see: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20754/why-does-spinning-help-stabilisation/20757#20757

Comment: Don't be discouraged. Ask another question.

Comment: *Welcome to Space!* This is an interesting topic for sure. Here are two things you can consider doing. 1) edit your question to make it different than the duplicate question (so that those answers do not answer your question) or what might be easier, ask a new question. You might ask *How do sounding rockets start spinning" or "How is the best rate of spin calculated for a given sounding rocket" for example. You can ask as many *good* questions as you like! Just do a quick check to make sure it hasn't been asked/answered already.

Comment: I've added two more tags to your question above. If you click those tags, you can see lists of questions that already use those tags. That's a quick way to check.